# How to pass a plist file to a (binary) assembly

Tags: ios, plist

I am building a library that is to be distributed as a binary assembly. The library provides a simulator for simulating events for testing purposes. The current implementation reads these events from a plist file that whose name is passed as an argument to the simulation selector. This works fine from the unit tests.

But when including the binary assembly file (.a) in another project, it is unable to open the passed plist file. The other project itself is able to open & parse the plist file in its own classes, though.

I assume this is due to the sandboxing mechanism that seems to apply to each library as well. Is there a way to pass a plist filename to an assembly so it can read it?

Comment: Is the plist file actually included in the app bundle?

Comment: Eiko yes it is. I figured out the mistake I did meanwhile - thanks for caring though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake: Unit tests are not bundled, so it's valid to pass just a filename there.

The app is bundled though, so to access the plist file I had to use:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SimulationScript" ofType:@"plist"]
```

This file can be read by both the app and the assembly without problems.